# Getting autocomplete placeholder and formControlName in Angular

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-reactive-forms

I am making use of the **mat-autocomplete** component with an input as per the examples in the docs, and I have configured the input with a **placeholder** and a **formControlName** like so:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Persona*" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="idPersona"
    [matAutocomplete]="autoPersonas">

    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoPersonas="matAutocomplete"
        [displayWith]="displayPersona(filteredOptionsPersonas | async)" (optionSelected)="selectedValue($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptionsPersonas" [value]="option.idPersona">
            <p>{{option.nombre}}</p>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

I'm also using **optionSelected** which emits **MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent** from mat-autocomplete to keep the viewvalue (option selected), the value, the formControlName and the placeholder. The problem is that I can't reach the last two (formControlName and placeholder) from the event object **MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent**. Is there a way to reach those properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them to the handler for the `optionSelected`.

So the method signature can change to `selectedValue(autoCompleteEvent: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, placeholder: string, controlName: string )`

And in your template: `(optionSelected)="selectedValue($event, 'Persona*', 'idPersona')"` .

Taking a guess here, but if your use case is to clean the control, then you can do it in the controller with subscribing to the controls changes and make an observable like this:

```
this.formGroup.get('idPersona').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  this.formGroup.get('idPersona').setValue(null, {emitEvent: false});
});
```

Setting the value to an empty string or null/undefined will make the placeholder reappear.

Comment: Thanks @tropicana ... I thought maybe there was a cleaner option to do it. I'm doing this because i wanna keep some data from all my form inputs in order to show a overview before confirming/submitting the form.

Comment: You can get the data out of the FormGroup then when it's value is changing or "on demand".

- `this.myFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(...)`
or  `this.myFormGroup.getValue();`

Comment: Yes, but I only store id values in myformGroup, so I wanna overview the text data that is displayed in each input, not the ids. I can't reach that information subscribing into myFormGroup, i guess...

Comment: You can add a reference to the ElementRef and then query the inputs with getElemementsByTagName('input'). For each input child, there should be a value property holding the information you need. For each input you can also query the attributes and get hold of the formControlName, then you can match the view value to the form control Id.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

Comment: thanks, i reading about and renderer2 api seems to be more secure. However, i have multiple form fields, and some of them are not inputs, for example textarea, selects, radio-button. I think i will try to manage with the first option u mentioned.